# MySQL - How do I import data from separate files into individual column cells?

Tags: xml, import, set, mysql-workbench, mysql-8.0

I have a table in MySQL that I have already imported table data into from a text file. However, one of the columns is all `NULL` and I need to import data from separate individual text files into each cell. For example, file1.txt content goes into the first cell in that column, file2.txt goes into the second cell in that column, and on and on...

I've come across some things stating that I need a SET statement for a LOAD_FILE process that involves concatenating the file path with some kind of variable statement to increment the file number. I'm not entirely sure if that's right and I've tried variations of what I thought might work. Appreciate if someone can lead me in the right direction with this!

Comment: *For example, file1.txt content goes into the first cell in that column, file2.txt goes into the second cell in that column, and on and on...* Does the relation is positional (i.e. the value from Nth row of file 1 and from Nth row of file 2 must be assigned to the same final row)? What is **precise** MySQL version?

Comment: Why you have tagged the question as XML-related? Does your text files are XML, not plain text?

Comment: MySQL 8.0. The files are .lob but the text is xml format

Comment: *The files are .lob but the text is xml format* The extension tells about nothing. Provide this text example (3-4 values).